# How can I get wireless working on an HP-Mini 110-3500, I have only usb ports

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers

How can I get wireless working on an HP-Mini 110-3500, I have only usb ports

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same 110-3500 that I just got, you do have an ethernet port, but it's hidden. It is located under a cover along the right side of the computer, at the rear - opposite where you plug in the power, and just behind the attachment point for a security lock cable.

I hope that helps. I'm in the process of installing ubuntu myself on one now.

Comment: can you add a picture, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Can you add some hardware information to your question?

- [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)

From my googling it looks like it could either be a broadcom card or an atheros card. Once we determine which wireless card it is we'll be able to help you better.

Do you have ethernet available? Usually plugging in via a wire and running Additional Drivers does the trick.

[image: hi]

Comment: no, I have only wireless adapter in my computer and usb ports. Wireless works ok with windows. But I couldn't anything in ubuntu network connection. Looks like I do not have the driver.